# Turning off angular hint

Tags: angularjs

Am I messing things up? I get angular hint stuff in my production site.

How do I make sure that the version of angular I'm using is production ready and not some dev version?

Comment: are you stripping out the angular hint script file as part of your build process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shot in the dark here because I just had this happen to me 5 seconds ago.. But If your using chrome and the extension, 'AngularJS' Batarang disable it.

For some reason it looks to be injecting the 'hint.js' into the DOM. Pretty much just had a heart-attack because it caused my app not to load in production!

UPDATE: Looks like it was indeed just updated as of 12/09/14
Changelog: https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/commits/master

UPDATE 2: Looks like the author is activly trying ot fix the problem as we speak! 
https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/158

Comment: Totally just screwed my site too.  Thanks for the fix.